# Join UNNESTED Values GoogleSQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have the following scenario

Table1

| Row | Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | [12345, 32145, 647834] | abcd |
| 2 | [23145, 11111, 12345] | efg |
| 3 | [647834, 23145] | zyx |
| 4 | [11111] | cba |

Table2

| Row | valuesforcol1 | names |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12345 | Jon |
| 2 | 32145 | Bob |
| 3 | 647834 | Jack |
| 4 | 23145 | Dave |
| 5 | 11111 | Alice |

Result

| Row | Col1 | Names |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | [12345, 32145, 647834] | [Jon, Bob, Jack] |
| 2 | [23145, 11111, 12345] | [Dave, Alice, Jon] |
| 3 | [647834, 23145] | [Jack, Dave] |
| 4 | [11111] | [Alice] |

How do I do that?

Comment: I'm confused.  What are the data type of the columns?  The sample data suggests arrays, but MySQL does not support arrays.  Are you using BigQuery by any chance?  Or perhaps Postgres?  "Google Cloud SQL" is not a specific database (https://cloud.google.com/sql); it is a way of paying for a variety of databases in the cloud.

Comment: BigQuery! Yes.. The data in col1 is array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were using BigQuery, then the logic would look like:

```
select t1.*,
       (select array_agg(t2.name order by n) as names
        from unnest(t1.col1) el with offset n join
             table2 t2
             on el = t2.valuesforcol1
       ) as names
from table1 t1
```

Comment: It worked! The "with offset n";. How did you find out about this expression? Any references that I could use?

Comment: @kos . . . It is right in the documentation:  https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays#flattening_arrays.